# Stable Fluids in 3D Example

Tags: c++, c, opengl, fluid

Has anyone run across or have an example of Jos Stam's Stable Fluids but in 3D?  I need to pursue a 3D version of this in openGL but have been having a terrible time doing so.  Is there an example of this preferably in openGL/C/C++?

Comment: What problems are you encountering?

Comment: "Stable Fluids"?  [This?](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/stam/reality/Research/pdf/ns.pdf).

Comment: Yes, that only in 3D.  I have seen plenty of 2D examples but no fully working 3D examples.  Just curious if anyone else is working on this.  Seems to be more on the research side of things I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best information I found about solving the Navier Stokes equitation (searched about 6 month ago): [link text](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/stam/reality/Talks/FluidsTalk/FluidsTalk_files/v3_document.htm). It explains every part of the equitation solver in the most easy way that I have ever found. I haven't looked intensively  into Jos Stam's paper, but it seems to be based on this equitation.

However the link I posted is also in 2D, but as the code is so easy, it should be no problem to add one (or even more xD) additional dimension.

Edit:I just realized that the talk that I have linked was held by Jos Stam :). Its a small world. Nevertheless the talk is better documented then the pdf, so I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Although this answer comes a few years late, it might still be useful:

3D implementation here:
http://graphics.ethz.ch/teaching/former/imagesynthesis_06/miniprojects/p3/

Another 3D implementation: https://code.google.com/p/smoke3d

Also, this thesis has source code at the end (Bongart, Robert)
http://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2007/rapporter07/bongart_robert_07018.pdf